# Don't include a comma after the last item in a printed list

Tags: c++

I have a list of numbers that are printed:

1: 1,
2: 1, 2,
3: 1, 3,

How do I not include that last comma on each line?

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= x; ++i )
  {
    cout << i << ": ";
    for ( int j = 1; j <= i; ++j )
    {
      if ( i % j == 0 )
      {
        cout << j << ", ";
      }
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
```

Comment: Please share with us your code...

Comment: how are you producing these numbers?

Comment: Cut it off with some scissors? Please post some code.

Comment: I recommend using the backspace key.

Comment: Instead, print the comma before every item but the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= x; ++i )
{
cout << i << ": ";
for ( int j = 1; j <= i; ++j )
{
  if (i==j) {
      cout << j;      
   } else if ( i % j == 0 ) {
       cout << j << ", ";
  }
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if number is the last, smth like:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
{
    cout << i << ": ";
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        if (!(i % j))
        {
            if (j != i)
                cout << j << ", ";
            else
                cout << j << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: Code added. Can't use arrays.

Comment: I've made a mistake, already correct it.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= x; ++i )
{
    cout << i << ": ";
    for ( int j = 1; j <= i; ++j )
    {
        if ( i % j == 0 )
        {
            cout << j;
            if (i != j) {
                cout << ", ";
            }
        } 
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you always output 1, start checking at 2

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= x; ++i )
{
   cout << i << ": 1";
   for ( int j = 2; j <= i; ++j )
   {
        if ( i % j == 0 )
        {
             cout << ", " << j;
        }
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, you could play with the separator

```
for ( int i = 1; i <= x; ++i )
{
   char sep = ':'
   cout << i;
   for ( int j = 1; j <= i; ++j )
   {
        if ( i % j == 0 )
        {
             cout << sep << " " << j;
             sep = ',';
        }
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```